# d3js line chart error - drawing weird area

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I haven't been able to find someone with a similar problem, and no clues to solve my problem reading the docs and other problems so I hope that some one can help me here.

This is my code (which is copied from the [documentation example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245))

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 150},
width = document.getElementById("aapp_content_charts").clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(3);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d3.time.year(parseDate(d[0]))); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });

var svg = d3.select("#aapp_content_charts").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


x.domain(d3.extent(list_indicators_3years_absolute['Gastos en activos financieros'] , function(d) { return parseDate(d[0]);}));
y.domain(d3.extent(list_indicators_3years_absolute['Gastos en activos financieros'] , function(d) { return d[1];}));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "xaxis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "yaxis")
  .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("(€)");

svg.append("path")
  .datum(list_indicators_3years_absolute['Gastos en activos financieros'])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

Now, you'd be wondering how my variable 'list_indicators_3years_absolute['Gastos en activos financieros']' looks like:

- From the console.log:

[Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHiX.png), Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHiX.png), Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHiX.png)]
0: Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHiX.png)
0: "2010"
1: 0
length: 2
**proto**: Array[0]
1: Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHiX.png)
0: "2011"
1: 29999996.8
length: 2
**proto**: Array[0]
2: Array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHiX.png)
0: "2012"
1: 79204931.01
length: 2
**proto**: Array[0]
length: 3
**proto**: Array[0]

- a more visual example of the variable: 
  [image]

Yes, there are only 3 points, for the three years (x axis): 2010, 2011, 2012

And here how the error "line" chart looks like:

[image]

I think the error is in my variable structure, but I don't get any warning, or clue to find out what is problem. In fact, both axis are set and labeled correctly, and the three points as well. The weird thing is that the line seems to be closed from the last point to the first one, and filled up.

:-mmmmm

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you are missing the `<style>` section from that example. The `fill: none` is what tells the line **not** to close from the last point to the first one:

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

You are telling it to use this class:

```
.attr("class", "line")
```

but if "line" doesn't exist in referenced CSS or inline styles you will get the default fill behavior.

See also: [D3.js tree with odd number of vertices, edges not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812875/d3-js-tree-with-odd-number-of-vertices-edges-not-shown/16816147#16816147)

Comment: :-OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO